# SQLplus expected symbol

Tags: sql, oracle

hello I'm new to SQL I'm attempting to create a database and am having an issue running this code in cmd sqlplus

```
execute 'CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE "COMPANY_DATA" DATAFILE 'c:\software\COMPANY_data_tablespace' SIZE 1G AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1024M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED LOGGING EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;'
```

I am receiving this error

```
Error at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column7:
PLS-00103: encountered the symbol execute 'CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE "MG_DATA" DATAFILE when expecting the following:
(begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pargma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<adouble-quoted delimited-identifier><a bind variable><<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set SQL execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

I'm not sure what I missing in the syntax I know this is a noobie question but kinda stumped thanks

Comment: Just remove `EXECUTE` and run the `CREATE ...` command directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is caused by the fact that you enclose the entire CREATE statement in single quotes, but the statement itself has embedded single quotes.  So the parser sees the first quote, and terminates that string when it sees the next. And that occurs when you hit the file name.  You'd need to escape the embedded quotes.

Or much better, as @GMB said, just submit the CREATE statement directly.  Why did you think you needed quote it and submit it with EXECUTE in the first place?